# Problems with automate Gradle Android Project and Crashlytics + Fabric.io in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have a project that was imported to IntelliJ, after cloned from git to my computer. All works fine to build, run and etc., but I'm trying to add Crashlytics in my project using Fabric plugin to IntelliJ. The plugin works fine, but the library wasn't imported, resulting in this problem:

[image: Problem with crashlytics]

My problem is: I need to import crashlytics + fabric library, but when I tried to add maven library dependency, I received the message that nothing found, when I thought in add dependency in build.gradle, my project don't have build.gradle, when I tried to create build.gradle, my problem wasn't solved and nothing happened...

[image: Project Structure]

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you added crashlytics to your project using gradle?

Comment: @ShubhadeepChaudhuri I added crashlytics using the Fabric plugin to IntelliJ. The plugin configs all automatically. My project uses gradle build tools, but haven't build.gradle file... Can you help me?

Comment: Have you imported this from an Eclipse project? If you have, did you export it to a gradle project first?

Comment: The project was very caotic, with ant build files, maven build files and gradle build files... I redid the project, just using gradle and copying sources/resources files to solve this problem. Thank you guys.